# How to export integrated library parameters to excel (PLM not linked to altium)

Tags: pcb-design, altium, script

I work for a small company. We use a PLM system (Arena) to manage components, as required by different departments like purchasing. We also use Altium 365, the standard version, for our CAD system. Unfortunately, syncing with the PLM system isn't possible due to our Altium version being the cheapest (365 standard).

Since Altium and the PLM system operate independently, our databases tend to drift over time. For instance, if someone updates something in Altium, they might forget to update it in the PLM system, and vice versa.

To address this issue, I want to export the integrated library parameters to Excel. I also aim to export all the equivalent parameters from the PLM system, allowing us to compare the two databases with minimal manual effort (using a excel script or something similar).

My question is: Can I export all the parameters from the integrated libraries, and if so, how? I've tried creating a DelphiScript in ChatGPT for this, but without success. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?